# Error in the environment variable with Railway in the ClientId in production, in local it works correctly

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, railway.js

I'm deploy a Node.js application to production with Railway , using Google's SignIn. When placing the environment variables in Railway it shows me an error. But if it is the correct ClientId. How could I correct it?

[The image shows the error, underlined in red.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwKn7.png)

I also show the error in console, chrome

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Done, solved. The problem was because I hadn't put the production url in the Google ClientId JavaScript Authorizers.